# What does a Nibble mean?

Tags: memory, measurement

I've tried `ip addr show` to obtain my MAC address in ubuntu. What is the size of a MAC address? How does a nibble related to bits/bytes?

Comment: Have you tried to google these questions?

Comment: 4bits=1 nibble 8 bits=1 byte,etc.

Comment: 1 nibble is also one Hexadecimal digit (0-f, as the question was referring to MAC addresses).

Answer (score 2):

A nibble is 4 bits  which is equivalent to one hexadecimal digit in a MAC address. A MAC address has 12 hexadecimal digits = 48 bits.

[image]